# How make multiple subqueries with Eloquent?

Tags: laravel

A have this code:

```
    DB::select('
        SELECT SUM(count) as count
          FROM (
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM ad_banners
            UNION ALL
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM ad_context
            UNION ALL
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM ad_content
            UNION ALL
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM ad_decoration
            UNION ALL
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM ad_front
            UNION ALL
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM ad_universal
          ) as ad'
    );
```

How make this query using Eloquent ORM methods and will this make sense? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I wrote this code, but my attempts to use Eloquent ended to fail. I don't understand how make sub queries with union and count. I didn't wont to write my code for me, it will be enough a small example. And sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You need to post what you have already tried. We aren't here to write your code for you.

Comment: I wrote this code, but my attempts to use Eloquent ended to fail. I don't understand how make sub queries with union and count. I didn't wont to write my code for me, it will be enough a small example. And sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `DB::raw()` method? Sometimes, if you know the SQL you want to use but don't know how to use Eloquent to accomplish it, you may use `DB::raw()` to get the results you need. Here's an example, you can tailor it to your needs:

```
$query = DB::connection('connection_name')->select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ..."));
```

Also, `connection_name` can be found as you defined it in `app/config/database.php` in the `connections` array.

Hope that provides some insight. Without an idea of your models and relationships and what you're trying to accomplish, it would be hard to advise you on an Eloquent solution to this issue.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any advantages of a Eloquent in front of a Query Builder? Which is better to use when there is not model?

Comment: Well, Eloquent is essentially a query builder that can use models if they are present. Personally, I would use Eloquent over MySQLi or PDO because I find it easier. They all do the same thing, but I like the syntax on Eloquent (most of the time anyway). In the end, it will be up to your personal preference.